# How to move the srv directory to another partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, partitioning

When installing Ubuntu (10.04) I chose the ***/home*** to be installed in a separate partition.
I would now like to move the ***/srv*** directory into the same partition.

The problem I found is that Ubuntu did not make a ***/home*** directory inside the partition itself.  It just places the account directories in the partition and mounts it to ***/home***.  So I cannot just easily move the ***/srv*** folder into the partition.

How can I:

1. Move those account directories into a home folder inside the partition
2. Make that new **home** folder the default ***/home*** folder.
3. ditto with the ***/srv*** folder, or any I choose in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Once `/home` has been mounted, you can do a **bind mount** to mount e.g. `/home/srv` on `/srv`.

```
mount --bind /home/srv /srv
```

In this case, the same files will appear under `/home/srv` and `/srv`.

Or you can do a **move mount** to move `/home/srv` to `/srv`.

```
mount --move /home/srv /srv
```

In this case, `/home/srv` will no longer exist after the mount. Unmounting `/srv` will make `/home/srv` appear again.

Comment: +1 for bind... I tried the move mount on a test directory but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do, it's not *exactly* possible - mounting doesn't work that way. (Although you can kind of fake it, as explained in e.g. Ignacio's answer)

You can think of each partition as its own filesystem. So for example, let's say you have a partition `sda1` that you're going to use for the root of the overall filesystem, and `sda2` that you're going to use to hold home directories. As you now know, the filesystem on `sda1` contains top-level directories `bin`, `lib`, `usr`, `home`, etc., and the filesystem on `sda2` contains top-level directories `user1`, `user2`, etc. (or whatever your users' home directories are called). The hierarchy might look like this:

```
sda1
|-bin
| |- (programs)
|-home
|-lib
| |- (libraries)
|-usr
| |-bin
| |-lib
| |-share

sda2
|-user1
| |-Documents
|-user2
| |-Documents
```

And also as you know, in order to mount a filesystem, you have to specify the filesystem (of course) and a directory, the *mount point*. When you do this, the directory you specify becomes the name for the root of the partition's filesystem. For example, one of the first things the OS does when starting up is mount `sda1` (in this example) on the directory `/`. That makes `/` the name for the root of the filesystem on `sda1`. You can now refer to the `bin` directory on `sda1` as `/bin`, for example. Later on in the boot process, the OS mounts `sda2` on `/home/`, which means that `/home/` is the name for the root of the `sda2` filesystem. To refer to the `user1` directory on `sda2`, you can write `/home/user1`. And so on.

Now it sounds like what you had in mind was assigning a name (like `/srv/`) to some subdirectory within a partition's filesystem, rather than the root of that filesystem. But `mount` doesn't work that way. I'm not sure whether there's a technical reason for that, or it was just a design decision by the maintainers of the Linux kernel. The bottom line is, in order to have anything on a partition accessible, you have to assign a name to the root of the filesystem. But once you do that, you can make subdirectories within the partition's filesystem accessible under other names using the `--bind` option to `mount`, and that's probably your best option.

Comment: It's just *nix legacy.

Answer (score 1):

in your case, /home is considered the "mountpoint", the name of the mountpoint can be changed by editing /etc/fstab

Answer (score 0):

Mount the partition as `/data`, add directories `/data/home` and `/data/srv`.

Now you can either simply symlink `/home` -> `/data/home` and `/srv` -> `/data/srv`:

```
sudo ls -s /data/home /home
sudo ls -s /data/srv  /srv
```

Or use `mount --bind`. In `/etc/fstab/` that would be:

```
sudo /data/home /home none bind 0 0
sudo /data/srv  /srv  none bind 0 0
```

I think that's all you need. Someone please correct if different options are needed for the fstab entries.

I have used the symlinks approach for years and it seems to work fine. Perhaps there is a performance hit for following the link, but I haven't noticed it. The bind method is probably better though, and I plan to use that going forward (assuming I haven't overlooked an issue/downside).